# Application crashed with access violation exception (0xC0000005) when exiting

Tags: c#, .net, crash, clr, rcw

The application is a WPF application based on .NET Framework 4.5. It is built in x86 mode, and running on Windows 7 (32bit).

When **exiting** the application by clicking the close button of the main window, it crashed sometimes.

This is main info analyzed from the dump file.

> In XXX.exe.824.dmp the assembly instruction at clr!RCW::EnterContext+18 in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll from Microsoft Corporation has caused an access violation exception (0xC0000005) when trying to write to memory location 0x00000008 on thread 2

This is the call stack info from the dump file.

```
  Source                       Arg 1       Arg2        Arg3        Arg4

clr!RCW::EnterContext+18     7e6ec72     3d9ab88     c4e7d31     381f8ac    
clr!RCW::ReleaseAllInterfacesCallBack+41     5745bc0     c4e7d21     381f8ac     17aee40    
clr!RCW::Cleanup+41     3d9ab88     7e6e944     0000000     381f8f0    
clr!RCWCleanupList::ReleaseRCWListRaw+d     0000000     381f8f0     0000000     381f8cc    
clr!RCWCleanupList::ReleaseRCWListInCorrectCtx+d1     0305028     c4e7d91     035a148     0000209    
clr!RCWCleanupList::CleanupAllWrappers+14d     c4e78a9     0000000     02aa860     0000001    
clr!RCWCache::ReleaseWrappersWorker+22d     0000000     c4e78d9     0000000     5e9bccc    
clr!ReleaseRCWsInCaches+59     c4e7b01     0000000     5e9bccc     02a0460    
clr!InnerCoEEShutDownCOM+76     c4e7bd5     7eb1f23     0000000     02a0460    
clr!WKS::GCHeap::FinalizerThreadStart+38a     0000000     0000000     0000000     0000000    
clr!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+4d     02a0460     381ffb0     73537f5     02a0460    
kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+e     02a0460     ba58f32     0000000     0000000    
ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+70     7f2a8c0     02a0460     0000000     0000000    
ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+1b     7f2a8c0     02a0460     0000000     0000000
```

Here is another one from WinDbg:

```
[0x0]   ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet   
[0x1]   ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects + 0xc   
[0x2]   KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx + 0x100   
[0x3]   kernel32!WaitForMultipleObjectsExImplementation + 0xe0   
[0x4]   kernel32!WaitForMultipleObjects + 0x18   
[0x5]   kernel32!WerpReportFaultInternal + 0x186   
[0x6]   kernel32!WerpReportFault + 0x70   
[0x7]   kernel32!BasepReportFault + 0x20   
[0x8]   kernel32!UnhandledExceptionFilter + 0x1af   
[0x9]   ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart + 0x62   
[0xa]   ntdll!_EH4_CallFilterFunc + 0x12   
[0xb]   ntdll!_except_handler4 + 0x8e   
[0xc]   ntdll!ExecuteHandler2 + 0x26   
[0xd]   ntdll!ExecuteHandler + 0x24   
[0xe]   ntdll!RtlDispatchException + 0x127   
[0xf]   ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatcher + 0xf   
[0x10]   clr!RCW::EnterContext + 0x18   
[0x11]   clr!RCW::ReleaseAllInterfacesCallBack + 0x41   
[0x12]   clr!RCW::Cleanup + 0x41   
[0x13]   clr!RCWCleanupList::ReleaseRCWListRaw + 0xd   
[0x14]   clr!RCWCleanupList::ReleaseRCWListInCorrectCtx + 0xd1   
[0x15]   clr!RCWCleanupList::CleanupAllWrappers + 0x14d   
[0x16]   clr!RCWCache::ReleaseWrappersWorker + 0x22d   
[0x17]   clr!ReleaseRCWsInCaches + 0x59   
[0x18]   clr!InnerCoEEShutDownCOM + 0x76   
[0x19]   clr!WKS::GCHeap::FinalizerThreadStart + 0x38a   
[0x1a]   clr!Thread::intermediateThreadProc + 0x4d   
[0x1b]   kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk + 0xe   
[0x1c]   ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart + 0x70   
[0x1d]   ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart + 0x1b
```

I have tried add the following config in the application config file(xxx.exe.config), while none of them takes effect.

```xml
    <configuration>
      <runtime>
        <legacyCorruptedStateExceptionsPolicy enabled="true" />
        <gcConcurrent enabled="false" />
      </runtime>  
    </configurtion>
```

So how to handle or avoid the crash?

Comment: Are you locked in to Win 7? That's really really really a _bad_ idea.

Comment: Are you making use of COM objects in your app?  e.g. Office?

Comment: It is likely that there's a bug in your code. Can you post an [mcve]? It is likely that you are not properly disposing of a COM object. That could be a bug in your own code, or a component you're taking a dependency on. The first thing I would do however, is upgrade to the latest version of Win10. No machine running Win7 should be connected to the power grid, much less any communications network.